# Alternatives to PHP-clamav for using on shared server?

Tags: php

I was planning to use `php-clamav` in one of my projects as it was easy to use but I have been notified that I cannot use it because I have `shared hosting account` and I can only use it if I have a VPS or Dedicated server.

The purpose of using PHP-clamav was/is to scan users uploaded files as I allow users upload files onto my server.

What are my options and what other alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClamAV is a great piece of software, not that much about its PHP counterpart. I tried the same some months ago and, to my surprise, php-clamav is quite an unmaintained piece of code.

You have two options:

- try to interface with ClamAV through the command line and parse its results
- use an online virus scanning service with a PHP API or a REST endpoint

In you case, option A may not be an option, as you're on a shared hosting and I don't know what kind of access will they give to you for such a task.

If you go for an online service, I could give you a couple of links (I haven't still tested them, they're on my TODO list, but they look promising):

- [ScanThis](http://scanthis.net/read/api) (looks quite easy and it's free)
- [Metascan online](https://www.metascan-online.com) (it comes with PHP samples to hook it up)
- [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/documentation/public-api/) (now acquired by Google, looks like a good service)

Other than that, I can't really give you any recommendation but, for the time being, thumbs down for php-clamav. It should be the way to go, but it's absolutely unworkable if you're on PHP 5.4.x+ (at least, for me)

Comment: nice one mate. I think i will have to go for the B option.

Comment: one question about ScanThis, I can't seem to find any PHP code or API related codes on their site! am i missing something?

Comment: No, they're not exposing any PHP example code, but they're showing you how to deal with the REST endpoint. You just need to use cURL (for example) to communicate with it. A good tutorial on how to use cURL for consuming REST services is here: `http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/using-curl-and-php-to-talk-to-a-rest-service`